# Using DPAPI to store RijndaelManaged key

Tags: c#

I'm using C#.
I have a private key with size of 256 bytes,

I'm trying to use `DPAPI` as follow:

```
  RijndaelManaged key = new RijndaelManaged();
  byte[] buffer = new byte[32]
        {
                3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,
                5,5,5,5,5,5,5,57,
                6,7,8,8,8,8,8,3,
                1,33,36,39,39,39,31,37
        };

        byte[] secret = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};

        // Encrypt a copy of the data to the stream.
        byte[] output = ProtectedData.Protect(buffer, secret, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
        key.Key = output;//Throw an exception
```

My problem that `output` array thats return from `ProtectData.Protect` is with size that `key.Key` isn't supported (178 bytes) and when i'm trying to insert the `output` into that RijndaelManaged key i'm got an exception:

> 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm.

How can i solve it? or any another solution to store my RijndaelManaged  key?

I want also to access to my private key from another proccess

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `ProtectedData.Protect` is encrypted (not an encryption key).  It grows to store whatever context and integrity checking it needs to prove that it can decrypt correctly.  To get your original 256-bit key back you would need to call `Unprotect`.

If you're trying to derive a key (instead of encrypt it) use a key derivation routine, like PBKDF2 (in .NET this is implemented by `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`).

Alternatively, if you're trying to use DPAPI to protect data, it does that inherently; you don't get to customize a key for it... just pass it the data to protect.

Comment: I just want to protect my private key

Comment: A "private key" means that asymmetric cryptography is involved. Rijndael (and the subset of Rijndael that is AES) is a symmetric algorithm, there's "the key", which should be secret, but no "private key". If you're trying to save it to disk and you're afraid of someone stealing your hard drive, DPAPI might help; but you would need to Unprotect the data to use it.  You can't hide the key from the current process. Before you can protect anything you need to describe when it should be protected, and from whom.

Comment: Ok..I'm understand. so you are right, as you say thats a private key that i want to save it to disk, i want to unprotect the data only per process/user logon or something like that.. i just want thats my "real" private-key will be hide if someone did reverse engineer to my exe